# What kind of program should be run on the customer PC to communicate with MySQL

Tags: java, mysql

I want to implement a program with Java to take orders from the callers of some restaurant. When taking the order and entering the telefon number or the caller id, a request is being sent to the database to check whether the caller has any related data (address) in the database. Consequently, some of the order fields is being filled.

After taking the order, a bill of cost must be printed with the name and address of the caller as well as the name and address of the resturant.

For such as a system, I have to work with JDBC to communicat with the MySQL database. My Question is what kind of database program has to be run on the PC in the resturant to able the jar file (the Program) to communicate with the database?

Comment: None. The JDBC driver communicates with the database directly, without needing any program on the client. The JDBC driver is downloadable here: https://dev.mysql.com/downloads/connector/j/, or in the Maven central repository: http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/mysql/mysql-connector-java

Comment: @JBNizet is right, assuming you already have a JDBC datasource properly configured, and the MySQL-J connector on the client system's classpath

Answer (score 0):

The "program" that you need to run is Java or, more specifically, a JRE (Java Run-time Environment).  The jar file you created needs to be executed within the JVM (Java Virtual Machine) which was started by the JRE.